# for loop in function using vba to do data masking

Tags: vba, data-masking

how do I replace the data that I want to mask without hard coding the * but replace the * with the number of letters that required masking?

I am new to VBA so i am using the C# and java logic to complete this. However the for loop in VBA is rather confusing to me

Comment: What I am doing now is hard coding a fix num of * to mask the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate a string of repeated characters, use the [String function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264797.aspx)

`String(6, "*")` will return `******`